# Configure nodemailer to function with no-reply configured sender email account

Tags: node.js, cpanel, nodemailer

I have the following code to send emails to my users from an account configured as a sender "noreply account, plus I added with the following forward filter":fail: No such person at this address. " into CPanel.

However I got an error with Nodemailer, so my question is how I could use a nonreply filter with nodemailer, any tricks I could do including probably changing the "from" field to show the recipients "noreply" account as the sender, while maybe able to send via another account ?

Note that sending works when I remove the filter from CPanel.

```
    const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'mail.myserver.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: 'noreply@myserver.com',
        pass: smtpPassword
      },
        tls: {
            // do not fail on invalid certs
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });


  const mailOptions = {
    from: `App <noreply@myserver.com>`,//`${APP_NAME} <${REPLY_EMAIL}>`,// 
    to: email
  };

    // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = subject
  mailOptions.text = text;

 return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => console.log(log, email))
    .catch(error => console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error));


**Nodemailer error log:**
 550-No such person at this address.
     550 Sender verify failed
       code: 'EENVELOPE',
       response: '550-Verification failed for <noreply@myserver.com>\n550-No such person at this address.\n550 Sender verify failed',
```

responseCode: 550,
       command: 'RCPT TO',

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Having the same issue over here...

Answer (score -1):

Use `service : 'gmail'` in the `mailTransport` object

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Errr... actually this seems to be a troll answer? There is not AFAIK, a `service` property available on the config for `nodemailer.createTransport()`. Nodemailer's docs actually kinda discourage use of Gmail, and where they do provide examples using it, there is no such prop... Eg., https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/